# Allow copy to USB drive but not copy from it

Tags: windows, usb

I am wondering if it is possible to configure Windows 7 or Windows 10 to allow copying data to a USB drive but at the same time prevent data from being copied from the USB drive to the computer.

The background is that I want to prevent users to copy their data, software, viruses etc. from a USB drive to my system. But at the same time, I want to allow them to retrieve the data on the computer (or at least in a specified result path) with the help of a USB drive.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution yet, and I start to doubt if there is any. Of course I can block the complete USB drive, but that is not what I want, since I just want to block inbound data, not outbound data.

Comment: Have you tried Administrative Templates / System / Removable Storage Access ?

Comment: @KostiaShiian I did try this, but when I block read access, I can't write anymore as well, so this does not help me very much.